# How to print out a number with INT 10h

Tags: assembly, interrupt

I've checked wikipedia about different kinds of INT 10h functions. But I couldn't find one to print a number, I mean not a string but an integer. For instance, I need to cal 1+2+3+4 and print the output. How can I do?

Comment: If you wish us to do your homework, at least tell us the platform you are on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print an integer above 9 directly using int 10h.  Instead you would need to write a macro/function to convert a single digit into a character by getting the number and adding it to '0' (30h).  Then you would need to write a further function to get each of the digits from the integer that you wanted to display.  E.g. if the integer can be a maximum of 5 digits (an 8 bit number), then divide it by 10000 and this is the first digit, or nothing if 0, then 1000 for the second digit, etc  Put these in a string and then you can call int 10h with that.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to a string then call `int 10h` with that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `int 10h`, you will have to do this digit by digit. For the offset for digits, check the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/): To print a `0`, load `0 + 48` into `AH`.